# C# -wcf Web service need to connect SOA web service with soap header passing username/password token. How to alter soap header?

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, soa

I have a WCF web service. In that I need to utilize SOA web service. I have created Reference.cs with WSDL file. Everything seems to be fine but SOA service expect custom header with Token including username\password. SOA team has given only username\password to pass in header. Now how to alter the SOAP header to pass authentication token in c# wcf?

Here is SOA expecting SOAP content

```
<message>
<properties>
<property  name="tracking.compositeInstanceId"  value="160008"/>
<property  name="tracking.ecid"  value="ef41c1acc87d807b:47c8a7e5:13aba83ab3c:-8000-000000000006d79c"/>
<property  name="transport.http.remoteAddress"  value="10.100.21.228"/>
</properties>
<headers>
<header>
<wsse:Security  soap:mustUnderstand="1">
<wsse:UsernameToken  wsu:Id="UsernameToken-njZlxs5jA9tMZ9zdXhHIaw212">
<wsse:Username>meuser</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password  Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">welcome123</wsse:Password>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
</header>
</headers>
<parts>
<part  name="request">
<ns1:DoT_GIS_Inbound_Input>
<ns1:InterfaceID>DOT_CRM_GIS_SBL_003</ns1:InterfaceID>
<ns1:ContactFirstName>Fname</ns1:ContactFirstName>
<ns1:ContactLastName>LName</ns1:ContactLastName>
<ns1:ComplaintType>Parking</ns1:ComplaintType>
<ns1:RequestType>Complaint Request</ns1:RequestType>
<ns1:Phone>5555555</ns1:Phone>
<ns1:ReportedDate>12\12\2012</ns1:ReportedDate>
<ns1:UniqueID>ddffketto7878998</ns1:UniqueID>
<ns1:Email>anji@yahoo.com</ns1:Email>
<ns1:Description>description text</ns1:Description>
</ns1:DoT_GIS_Inbound_Input>
</part>
</parts>
</message>
```

My WCF service's method  as below

```
public string CreateComplaintInCRM(string TYPE, string DESCRIPTION, string DATE_REPORTED, string EMAIL, string Phone, string Contact_Name, string UNIQUE_ID, string Contact_SName)
     {

                CRMCreateComplaint.DoT_GIS_Inbound_Input crmCreateObj = new CRMCreateComplaint.DoT_GIS_Inbound_Input();
                CRMCreateComplaint.execute_pttClient exeRec = new CRMCreateComplaint.execute_pttClient();

                crmCreateObj.InterfaceID = "DOT_CRM_GIS_SBL_003"; // CRM setting 
                crmCreateObj.RequestType = "Complaint Request"; //// CRM setting 
                crmCreateObj.ComplaintType = TYPE;//compalint type
                crmCreateObj.ContactFirstName = Contact_Name;
                crmCreateObj.ContactLastName = Contact_SName;
                crmCreateObj.Description = DESCRIPTION;
                crmCreateObj.Email = EMAIL;
                crmCreateObj.UniqueID = UNIQUE_ID;
                crmCreateObj.Phone = Phone;
                crmCreateObj.ReportedDate = DATE_REPORTED;

                //string COMPLAINTREFID = exe.execute(crmCreateObj);

                exeRec.execute(crmCreateObj);
                return "Referece ID:";
            }
```

I get InvalidSecurity : error in processing the WS-Security security header.

Any SOA developer in C# out there who has same kind of problem ? 
Your help and guide is highly appreciate.

I have gone though lot of document and articles and none help properly

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms819938.aspx

requestContext.Security.Tokens.Add(userToken);